# SQL statement with DatabaseLibrary in Eclipse (rbfw) return jibberish instead of only the exact value

Tags: sql, database, shared-libraries, robotframework

I'm using the RobotFramework in Eclipse and the DatabaseLibrary

(https://franz-see.github.io/Robotframework-Database-Library/api/0.5/DatabaseLibrary.html)

---

This is the statement I use:

```
${test}=  DatabaseLibrary.Query    select Location from Devices where DeviceID = '2'
    Log to Console  ${test}  console=yes
    Should Be Equal As Strings    ${test}    Amsterdam
```

The value in the database is   `Amsterdam`

however, what I get back is `(('Amsterdam',),)

Why is that and how can it return  `Amsterdam` ?
(the actual value without the jibberish extra's)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document for query keyword says following:

`Uses the input selectStatement to query for the values that will be returned as a list of tuples.`

And your return value is:

```py
(('Amsterdam',),)
```

Which is "a list of tuples" - so everything is as they should be.

If you need to access list elements, you can use `[]`'s with indexes. Something like this might work:

```
    ${test}=  DatabaseLibrary.Query    select Location from Devices where DeviceID = '2'
    Log to Console  ${test[0][0]}  console=yes
    Should Be Equal As Strings    ${test[0][0]}    Amsterdam
```

Answer (score -1):

I figured out a workaround as well:

```
Should Match Regexp    str${test}    ^\\w*\\W*Amsterdam*\\w*\\W*$
```